# GCC causes segfault for lambda-captured parameter pack

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda

I have the following SSCCE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(const std::string &a) {
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

template <typename... Args>
void bar(Args &&... args) {
  [&]() {
    [&]() {
          foo(args...);
      }();
  }();
}

int main() {
 const std::string x("Hello World!");
 bar(x);
}
```

Under clang++ (3.9.1) this compiles and emits "Hello World". Gcc 6.3 fails with a segmentation fault under `-O3`.

I can fix the problem by explicitly passing the pointer and the pack by reference, replacing `[&]()` with `[&args...]()`. However, up to now, I thought that `[&]` would do the same as listing all arguments one by one.

So what is going wrong here?

P.S:
This is not limited to `-O3`. `-O0` does not segfault but does not return the expected result ("Hello World!"):

```
[:~/tmp] $ g++-6 -std=c++1z param.cpp && ./a.out

[:~/tmp] $
```

P.P.S: Further reduced SSCCE. Now I don't even get a diagnostic with `-Wall -Wextra` anymore.

Comment: Seems to only happen with optimization.

Comment: Can't confirm - happens for me with `-O0` as well (see addendum)

Comment: @Exagon, Of course it can be passed around by reference. It can't be copied, though. Here's an example: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lj4SQhth5iis81FG

Comment: @mrks My bad, I noticed a lack of segfault, but forgot it was supposed to produce output.

Comment: @mrks my bad, of cause it can be passed by reference sorry

Comment: Updated the example, doesn't have anything to do with `unique_ptr`.

Comment: `warning: 'args#0' is used uninitialized in this function` Obvious bug.

Comment: Apparently only happens with 1) two levels of captures by default (`=` or `&`) and 2) a parameter pack.

Comment: One thing that is missing in your example is `#include <string>` however. VC++ will not compile without it

Comment: Thanks. The other compilers seem to be more lenient about that. Will update in a second.

Comment: clang and VC++ will work and the syntax looks valid. My guess is it's a g++ bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I strongly suspect a **g++ bug**.

---

Here are some notes:

- replacing `std::string` with any elementary type, e.g., `int` [**still does not work**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5bpRvEBF7ew2iAS0)
- [clang](http://rextester.com/GLSKDS37328) and [VC++](http://rextester.com/EQVB17367) will work just as intended
- not passing parameter pack by reference causes an [**internal compiler error with g++ 7.0.1**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mYtVweIn8zv4t74Y) with the following output:

> internal compiler error: in make_decl_rtl, at varasm.c:1304
>
> ...
>
> Please
> submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>
> Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report. See
> http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html for instructions.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I filed a bug at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79180